# How windows 7 detects that the pc connected to the internet?

Tags: connection

When internet connection losts on pc (But local LAN works correctly and neighbour computers accessible), The Windows 7 detects internet connection losts.

Which algorithm used by Windows to detect internet connectivity?

Is there any API to use this feature in my applications?

**Note**: [InetIsOffline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776460%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API always returns "internet is connected"! Even when my network cable is not connected to my pc.

Comment: Since connectivity to the internet is outside of the control of your application, and may come and go at any time, there's very little value in determining this information programatically. If you need to do something in your application that involves remote servers, go ahead and try to do it (hopefully not on a UI thread), and deal with interruptions, timeouts, etc. You need to include such code in your app anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows 7 pings a Microsoft server.  If it gets a response, internet is on.

More detailed (wordy) explanation here: http://blog.superuser.com/2011/05/16/windows-7-network-awareness/

Comment: Do you mean if Microsoft servers down, Windows reports no internet activity?

Comment: Exactly.  Well, what is the internet exactly?  It's just a bunch of computers connected using a set of protocols.  If a big bunch of the computers aren't responding to you (which is what I'd expect would happen for the Microsoft servers to be down), then either your connection to your ISP is borked, or the internet has started to fragment.